# RecyclerView is not Displaying any Items

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using Fragments in my code. Fragment One and Fragment two contains Recycleview and MainActivity attaches this two Fragments. I am not seeing any error in the code or in the error log. I can see JSON output in the log as well. Any help is appreciated.

I am running this program in Kotlin. I created this code and no error in the code.

**Fragment One**

```
class HomeFragmentOne : Fragment()
            {
    private var adapter: CandyOneAdapter?=null
    private var candyList: ArrayList<Food>?=null
    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager?=null

                var volleyRequest:RequestQueue?=null
                var candyOneLink="http://abc.app"


                companion object
                {
                    val TAG=HomeFragmentOne::class.java.simpleName
                    @JvmStatic
                    fun newInstance()=HomeFragmentOne()
                }
            }
```

My desired output is If I click the Home by default it should show FragmentOne Item and If click that FragmentOne then it should show Fragment Two and If I click FragmentTwo Item then It should show FragmentOne Item. Follwing is the workflow. Home--->FragmentOne---->FragmentTwo---->FragmentOne.

Comment: You need to add the items to your list, and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @dharms Thanks and it worked but I have one questions. 1)If I clicked HomeFragmetTwo and its not going back to HomeFragmentOne.

Comment: Since that is a separate issue, I'd suggest asking a separate question with the relevant code so it is usable by others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged() will resolve this issue.